# Prettier methods in Go Lang

Tags: go

I am looking for best practices while writing Go code. I have two methods they are very close in logic. I just want to code it better and is there a way of combining AddAuthor and AddTitle methods in one with Go.

I am thinking something like func (t *Test) SetProperty("name", "alfa") .. kind of an approach but don't know how to make this code better. Any comments are welcome. Also if you give me a link with well written Go Code in terms of style and practices, I would be glad.

Thanks,

```
type Test struct {                                                                                                                  
    Title          string                                                       
    Author         string                                                       
}                                                                               

func (t *Test) AddAuthor(name string) (*Test, error) {                          
    if err := validateStringLength(name); err != nil {                          
        return nil, err                                                         
    }                                                                           
    t.Author = name                                                             
    return t, nil                                                               
}                                                                               

func (t *Test) AddTitle(title string) (*Test, error) {                          
    if err := validateStringLength(title); err != nil {                         
        return nil, err                                                         
    }                                                                           
    t.Title = title                                                             
    return t, nil                                                               
}                                                                               

func validateStringLength(field string) error {                                 
    if len(field) > 255 {                                                       
        return fmt.Errorf("field %v is too long.", field)                       
    }                                                                           
    return nil                                                                  
}
```

Comment: Why do you return `t`? You're mutating `t`, you don't have to return it unless you change something fundamental about it (like `append` does)

Comment: ahh you are right, I spent too much time in Ruby zone forgot about all pointers :( thank you very much

Comment: I had to swap back full time to Python about a month after beginning to learn Go to finish a project under very tight deadlines. Came ban to Go Land after three weeks remembering almost NOTHING. I feel your pain!

Comment: If you want to do assignment validation, do not expose the fields or they will be abused for sure. Also, name your function SetFieldName for fields setter and FieldName for fields getter.

Comment: Agreed with @nevets. This is the way to do it https://bitbucket.org/snippets/smith_adam/yrbEx

Comment: and i'm backed up with Effective Go here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters

Comment: thanks for your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
func (t *Test) AddAuthor(author string) (*Test, error) {
  return t.setString(&t.Author, author)
}

func (t *Test) AddTitle(title string) (*Test, error) {
  return t.setString(&t.Title, title)
}

func (t *Test) setString(p *string, v string) (*Test, error) {
  if len(v) > 255 {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("field %v is too long.", v)
  }
  *p = v
  return t, nil
}
```